# What are the downsides of 'inline __attribute__ ((forced_inline))' compared to '#define'?

Tags: c, embedded

It seems like `inline __attribute__ ((always_inline)) - fn(-)` is better than `#define fn(-)` (embedded C context) because it does the same thing without causing weird text-replacement related issues. What are its downsides? Why do people use `#define` functions instead?

Comment: Because inlining isn't an universal replacement for function-like macros. Often you want the macro parameters to expand to something that isn't data, but other pre-processor symbols.

Answer (score 0):

A reason: `#define` is standard C.

`inline __attribute__ ((always_inline))` is not - lost of portability.